# Passing data from one page (within jQuery Dialog) to another

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How can I pass a selected value of an element in a jQuery dialog to its parent page?

Page1.aspx

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnLookUp").click(function() {
            $("#searchActor").dialog({
                autoOpen: "false",
                resizable: "false",
                height: "250",
                width: "320"
            });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSearch").click(function() {
            $("#actorsList").load("LookUp/ActorsList.aspx", { lname: $("#txtSearchCriteria").val() });
        });
        return false;
    });

    function SelectGrid(objValue, itemValue , popUpDialog) {
        $(objValue).val(itemValue);
        $(popUpDialog).dialog("close");                       
    }
```

ActorsList.aspx Codebehind

```
private void LoadActors(string param)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //Execute stored proc

        Response.Write("<table>");
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Response.Write("<tr>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + "<label onclick='SelectGrid(#txtActorId,0,#searchActor'>Select</label>" + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + dr[2].ToString() + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + dr[3].ToString() + "</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>" + dr[4].ToString() + "</td>");
            Response.Write("</tr>");
        }
        Response.Write("</table>");
    }
```

`

Also, please help me with this line, I'm having trouble how to assign the value so I just placed it as 0.
`Response.Write("<td>" + "<label onclick='SelectGrid(#txtActorId,0,#searchActor'>Select</label>" + "</td>");`

Answer (score 0):

In the parent window you need to create an event listener(please note that this is now an absolutely cross-browser solution, here's support [list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging))

```
function listener(event) {
  if( event.origin != 'http://your-domain.com') { //means data comes from another domain
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Recieved: " + event.data;
}

if (window.addEventListener){
  window.addEventListener("message", listener, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onmessage", listener);
}
```

in the frame form where you wont to send data:

```
var win = window.parent;
win.postMessage("Hello", "http://your-domain.com");
```

if you need the description for the fully cross-browser solution feel free to ask in comment, the general approach is threw "hashbangs"

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want to achieve this kind of lookup found on this link http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=6942119, the data that will be displayed in the dialog will be coming from another page.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario of the code posted above is like this, I have a lookup button, when the user clicks on that button, it will load the searchactor dialog (a jquery dialog).  In this dialog, the user can able to search for list of actors where, it loads an aspx page (ActorsList.aspx).  The user will select an actor on the list (that is within the lookup dialog) and it will be displayed on the Actor Id (txtActorId).  That is why I have a function named SelectGrid to send the data from the lookup dialog to Page1.aspx.  I found a page http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=6942119 where it does the same thing, however, in my case, I load the data on the jquery dialog from a separate page.